# How do I add a MongoDB to a React Web App that I have already made lots of progress in?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, database, mongodb, react-native

[image: My file structure]

I'm using a Mac, I already have a cloud Atlas account, but I'm struggling to know how to connect to it? How to start my database? If you could point me in the direction of a tutorial that explains it? I find lots of tutorials miss out important information or don't fully explain why they do things. Cheers!!

Answer (score 0):

1. First, you need to configure the connection between Atlas and Node.js on your server (I recommend you use Mongoose for this step), maybe [this tutorial](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/connections.html) can help you.
   **Notice that on the URI you must use the *mongodb+srv* protocol. Also, you must use your username and password of your Atlas Account when you declare it. I recommend you put this information (user and password) on [env variables](https://medium.com/the-node-js-collection/making-your-node-js-work-everywhere-with-environment-variables-2da8cdf6e786).**
2. [Create your endpoints](https://scotch.io/@gilles/get-started-with-creating-a-restful-api-endpoints-in-nodejs-and-expressjs) to manage your Mongo entities on your node.js server (read, create, edit or delete).

   ```
   // You must create this model according the Mongoose docs.
   const MyMongooseModel = require('./models/MyMongooseModel');


   // Dummy example of the very simple logic of one endpoint
   app.get("/dummy", (req, res, next) => {
       // Maybe you need to apply a better management of the DB calls.
       // Avoid call the DB directly on the endpoint, this is only an example.
       MyMongoseModel.findOne(/* Mongoose opts. */);
   });
   ```
3. Use [Axios](https://github.com/axios/axios) on your React.js project to call your endpoints.

   ```
   axios.get('your-api-host/dummy')
     .then(function (response) {
       console.log(response);
     })
     .catch(function (error) {
       console.log(error);
     })
     .then(function () {
       // always executed
     });
   ```

Essentially that's it.

Comment: Thank you so much for making it so easy to understand - I have finally managed to do it and I am soooo stoked!!! <3

Answer (score 0):

this is pretty easy once you get the hang of it all you need to do is create apis using express, that CRUD - create read update or delete - data from the mongodb database, and call the apis in react using something like fetch or axios, and preferrably store the data in a state so it can be used in your ui... a very good tutorial that drilled this into my brain was one by brad traversty named mern stack on udemy. i highly suggest you check it out

Comment: Thank you for explaining sooo easily and clearly!! I managed to do it, and it's the best feeling EVER :)